# Simplifying a boolean expression

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I'm working on the following problem:

[image: boolean expression]

I found the correct answer for part (i): 
$$
Z = \left(\overline{(\overline{A + B})C}\right) (C\overline{D})
$$
How can I simplify this expression?

Comment: [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) is helpful. There are also a lot of identity boolean expressions that would help. See [here](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~grundke/reference/boole.html).

Comment: The question is asking if there is a simpler Boolean expression to give the same outputs. It's asking you to apply [DeMorgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to find a simpler solution.  What have you tried?

Comment: This is the same type of question as "simplify the expression 5x + x - 3" except in logic. Apply a few transforms (eg: "not(A and B) -> (not A) or (not B)") and see what can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

[image]

For safety use Karnaugh:

[image]